# How to disable directory browsing/listing and also individual files of url in apach2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I have an Apache2 web server, which unfortunately allowed directory browsing.

I have managed to disable directory browsing, its showing 403 for url say "192.168.0.2/test-api" which is good and expected.

But when i browse to this url like this "192.168.0.2/test-api/app.js", i'm able to view all the details of that file and all individual files without login into this application.

So how to prevent or block file browsing in my case to disallow unauthorised users from viewing this critical info.

Comment: Is the `app.js` a client-side JavaScript application?

Comment: What is "this application"?  Can Apache verify if the request is made by a connection with a valid logon?   Probably not.  In that case requests for individual files should also be answered by the application, after it verifies the connection (eg. via session).

Comment: Within your apache config <directory /test-api/> Options -indexes </directory> should do the trick.  But this only works if there is no index file such as index.html in the folder. Not knowing what you have tried makes it harder to diagnose. Another option is to place a .htaccess file in each folder with Options -indexes